# Security considerations between database and file based storage of pictures

Tags: .net, image, security

I'm designing a social networking site and obvious photo privacy is a major factor.  Simply put how can I restrict certain photos to certain people?

I'm using .NET technologies (C# and SQL server).  Traditionally as web developers we prefer to store uploaded images on the hard drive for various factors (performance and storage size to name two).  However assuming these are stored in a directory available to the web are they secure?

I can generate random filenames but what's to stop an application coming along, finding my photo directory and just trying random filenames?  The more images and the more time the higher probability they'll find images they're not supposed to!

Does this mean database storage (where I can stream the data myself handling security as part of my application) or is my only option or is there another approach I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have the images stored on disk, but not directly available to the web
- Use the database to store the rights of each user over the images
- Build some web application that serves the images to the users allowed to

Comment: So my application would read the data from the disk and send via a HttpHandler (or similar) based on permissions?

Comment: I'm not C# expert, so I might not grasp fully what using a HttpHandler implies, but for what I checked right now, yes, that could be one way to do it